# How to determine whether a MS-Word paragraph is more than one line?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

What I want is not to find where enter was pressed in a paragraph (the end of a paragraph). I need to determine whether a paragraph contains a single line or multiple lines so that it can be formatted accordingly (centered or left-justified).

Like this in the center if it's in one line

[image]

or left justify if in Multiline

[image]

How to determine whether a paragraph is more than one line in VSTO?

Comment: Note that it's always a good idea to post some "framework" code for a question like this to give people a starting point. Otherwise 1) we have to write everything from scratch; 2) the code we offer will more closely match your code. IOW less work for everyone.

Comment: Did the contribution below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Since "lines" are not objects in the Word object model, due to its dynamic layout algorithms, this needs to be approached via the old WordBasic technology still built into the APIs. (WordBasic worked based on selections, rather than objects, which is why this capability is present in these old methods.)

In this case, the `Word.WdInformation` enumeration offers parameters that work with "lines", more specifically for this problem `wdFirstCharacterLineNumber`.

The following sample code contains a code snippet that calls `IsParaOneLine` on a specific paragraph of a document.

`IsParaOneLIne` *duplicates* the paragraph `Range` passed two it *twice*: once for the starting point and once for the end point. These Ranges are then collapsed to their starting and end points, respectively and the line number determined. If the two are the same, `true` is returned to the calling code, otherwise `false`.

Notes:

1. `rngEnd.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);` moves the end point back by one character because after collapsing to the end of a paragraph `Range`, the `Range` is at the start of the following paragraph. This moves it back to the original paragraph.
2. The example applies a style rather than "direct formatting". Rather than formatting with centered and left alignment throughout a document I strongly recommend using ***Styles***. If there's not a built-in style with the formatting required, create the custom styles you need. If you're familiar with CSS you know the advantages of using styles. With Word there's an additional reason: it massively reduces the temp files Word generates so that you're less likely to run out of memory.

   ```
        Word.Range rng = doc.Paragraphs[2].Range;

       if (IsParaOneLine(rng))
       {
           rng.set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1);
       }
       else
       {
           Debug.Print("Not one line");
       }


   public bool IsParaOneLine(Word.Range rng)
   {
       Word.Range rngStart = rng.Duplicate;
       rngStart.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);
       Word.Range rngEnd = rng.Duplicate;
       rngEnd.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
       rngEnd.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, -1);
       int posLineStart = (int) rngStart.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdFirstCharacterLineNumber);
       int posLineEnd = (int) rngEnd.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdFirstCharacterLineNumber);
       bool isSameLine = false;

       if (posLineStart == posLineEnd)
           isSameLine = true;

       return isSameLine;
   }
   ```